# Drupal6x: Tag content twice with terms from the same taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

Is there a way to tag content twice with terms from the same taxonomy vocabulary? The reason I'd want to do this is to allow tagging of content with multiple terms from a taxonomy vocabulary, but also tag the content with a "primary" term.

I embed the taxonomy selects as a CCK field from the taxonomy vocabulary page, by choosing the appropriate Content type.

What is an accepted way to do this, without creating identical taxonomy vocabularies? Do I need to create a module to sync to vocabularies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using content taxonomy 
http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy

We are using this module combined with the default taxonomy module to solve a simular problem.

You can approach this one of two ways.

No matter how you set things up you'd have a content taxonomy field that is limited to 1 entry for the "primary category"

Then you can either use the default taxonomy for the "additional categories" or use another content taxonomy field for them.

There are advantages to either approach, but I would lean toward a solution that uses all content taxonomy fields so that the theming is consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with mirzu that Content Taxonomy looks like a good bet. Also note that this is in core for Drupal 7. That is, you can create two fields that reference the same vocabulary, and have one as a drop-down select list and another as checkboxes/radio buttons (if that's what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an option to make 2 identical vocabulary. Or search module for synchronization of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use CCK mutli-selection field instead of second taxonomy vacabulary. I don't think you can attach one taxonomy vocabulary twice to a content type.

Comment: I need two fields because one should allow me to tag the content with 1+ categories, another should be a "primary category", meaning only one should be allowed.